# Bacula virtual backup job doesn't run, no output?

Tags: bacula

I am trying to get Virtual Backups working, but when I try to run a virtual backup job, it appears to get created, but then never seems to actually run.

I have a full, and a couple incremental backups.

```
status director
 JobId  Level    Files      Bytes   Status   Finished        Name 
====================================================================
  1283  Full     10,565    1.963 G  OK       21-Dec-12 09:47 nms-Job
  1284  Incr        314    129.6 M  OK       21-Dec-12 09:49 nms-Job
  1285  Incr        230    147.2 M  OK       21-Dec-12 09:51 nms-Job
  1288  Incr        525    138.8 M  OK       21-Dec-12 11:25 nms-Job
```

I attempt to start a job from `bconsole` like this.

```
*run job=nms-Job level=VirtualFull 
Using Catalog "MySQL"
Run Backup job
JobName:  nms-Job
Level:    VirtualFull
Client:   nms-FileDaemon
FileSet:  nms-FileSet
Pool:     nms-pool (From Job resource)
Storage:  File_d1 (From Pool resource)
When:     2012-12-21 13:07:54
Priority: 10
OK to run? (yes/mod/no): 
Job queued. JobId=1291
```

Then my new job, just sits there, doing nothing.  The JobStatus shows that the job was created, but it appears to never run?  All the full, and incremental backups are terminating normally.

```
*llist jobid=1291
           JobId: 1,291
             Job: nms-Job.2012-12-21_13.07.56_07
            Name: nms-Job
     PurgedFiles: 0
            Type: B
           Level: F
        ClientId: 4
            Name: nms-FileDaemon
       JobStatus: C
       SchedTime: 2012-12-21 13:07:54
       StartTime: 2012-12-21 13:07:56
         EndTime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
     RealEndTime: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        JobTDate: 1,356,124,076
    VolSessionId: 0
  VolSessionTime: 0
        JobFiles: 0
       JobErrors: 0
 JobMissingFiles: 0
          PoolId: 19
        PooLname: nms-pool
      PriorJobId: 0
       FileSetId: 11
         FileSet: nms-FileSet
```

I am getting very frustrated, that this isn't working, mostly because it isn't giving me any error logs, or output at all.  I submit the job, and as far as I can tell nothing happens.

Is there some status, or debugging level that I can set to get a useful information about why this isn't working?  What can I do to make this work?

I was originally running Bacula 5.0.2 on Debian Squeeze, out of frustration, I upgraded to the 5.2.6 in the backports repository, hoping that a new version might give me better results.

Comment: Debugging level can be set on bacula-dir's command line ('-d' flag).  Try '-d 100', then '-d 1000'.  '-f' is also recommended.

Comment: I have restarted the directoyr with -d 1000, and I have the output here.  https://gist.github.com/4392322

Comment: Line 71 `do-srv-05-dir: ua_run.c:1512-0 Using catalog=*None*`. Is `catalog=*none*` normal???

Comment: @JohnSiu that is an interesting question, but I have no idea. I am pretty new, bur I will look at that.

Comment: "set_jcr_job_status(nms-Job.2012-12-27_13.41.31_08, s)" -- 's' is "Waiting for storage resource".  What does "status storage" show?

Comment: @Zoredache In bconsole, try `run` and select the job from list.

Answer (score 0):

Type "messages" in bconsole and it will output all logs from jobs, but just once. Another way is to configure bacula director with good email, and it will send logs to that email.

Comment: Sorry, for the slow reply.  I get no messages, and I do have email setup, and get email all my other jobs.  Only the `VirtualFull` job just sits there with no output.

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with full backups writing to the same pool as the source inc/diff backups - do they not have to be different pools?

If you can post your config of pool and job definitions that would help.

I am currently working my way through this with the help of the following blog: http://metricmarketing.ca/blog/bacula-server-backup-complexities